# Unable to access formArray controls within a formGroup

Tags: angular

I have initialised a formGroup and added a formArray (which has 3 simple formGroups pushed to it):

```js
this.myFormGroup = this.fb.group({
  myFormControl: [''],
  myFormArray: this.fb.array([]),
})


get myFormArray() {
   return this.myFormGroup.get('myFormArray') as FormArray;
}

pushToMyArray(linkTitle: string, linkUrl: string) {
  this.myFormArray.push(this.fb.group({
    linkTitle: [linkTitle],
    linkUrl: [linkUrl],
  }))
}

[{linkTitle: '', linkUrl: ''},{linkTitle: '', linkUrl: ''},{linkTitle: '', linkUrl: ''}].forEach(x => {
  this.pushToMyArray(x.linkTitle, x.linkUrl)
});
```

I want to access the controls of the formArray so I can `.disable()` them, but when I try to loop through them, they don't seem to exist:

```js
// Shows that the controls exist:
console.log(this.myFormArray) // { controls:(3) [FormGroup, FormGroup, FormGroup], ...}
console.log(this.myFormArray.controls) // 0: FormGroup {_pendingDirty: false, ...
// Contradicting the above, these show that they don't exist when I try to access them:
console.log(this.myFormArray.controls[0]) // undefined
console.log(this.myFormArray.controls.length) // 0
```

Why is this happening and how do I access the formArray controls?

Answer (score 1):

```
const items = [{linkTitle: '', linkUrl: ''},{linkTitle: '', linkUrl: ''},{linkTitle: '', linkUrl: ''}];

items.forEach(item => {
  const group = this.fb.group({
    linkTitle: [item.linkTitle],
    linkUrl: [item.linkUrl],
  });
  this.myFormArray.push(group);
});

// Now you can access the controls of the FormArray like this:
const controls = this.myFormArray.controls;
```

Answer (score 0):

Gah, I realised that I was trying to access the controls in my code before they had actually been created. The initial `console.log` results were incorrect and not showing the live values.

I solved the issue by performing the `disable()` method immediately after I had added to the formArray:

```js
// code from original post:
[{linkTitle: '', linkUrl: ''},{linkTitle: '', linkUrl: ''},{linkTitle: '', linkUrl: ''}].forEach(x => {
  this.pushToMyArray(x.linkTitle, x.linkUrl)
});
// Add this code immediately after:
this.myFormArray.controls.forEach(x=> x.disable())
```